# MultiProvider in main instead of inside the tree

Tags: flutter, provider

Does inserting all providers in main affect performance? Is it a better option to put individual providers in the middle of the tree where they are needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When injecting many values in big applications, Provider can rapidly become pretty nested:

```
Provider<Something>(
  create: (_) => Something(),
  child: Provider<SomethingElse>(
    create: (_) => SomethingElse(),
    child: Provider<AnotherThing>(
      create: (_) => AnotherThing(),
      child: someWidget,
    ),
  ),
),
```

To:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<Something>(create: (_) => Something()),
    Provider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
    Provider<AnotherThing>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
  ],
  child: someWidget,
)
```

**

The behavior of both examples is strictly the same. MultiProvider only changes the appearance of the code.

**

Comment: I understand that, my question was more about whether it is better practice to use all the providers in the MultiProvider before the material app or to nest them in the widgets

Comment: In big applications,
It is better practice to use all the providers in the MultiProvider before the material app.

Answer (score 2):

Providers used in main are providers of settings or essential data for the application, for example:

- User language configuration;
- Dark/Light theme setting;
- Current user data;
- List of current user's notifications ( When a "bell icon" appears in the appBar on all screens for example )

When using nested providers, you have a dependency on when to update the top one on the stack and rerun the rest of the nested ones.

With the MultiProvider the execution is individual and asynchronous, prefer to use this one when you don't need to make a nested provider to another one that performs the processing of the first one.

Examples:

```
Provider<UserModel>(
   create: (_) => fetchUser(),
   child: Provider<PetModel>(
     create: (_) => fetchPets(),
     child: ...
   ),
),
```

In the example above pets are user dependent so it makes sense to be loaded nested.

But if we had more data that can be loaded along with pets, the example would look like this

```
Provider<UserModel>(
   create: (_) => fetchUser(),
   child: MultiProvider(
      providers: [
          fetchFamily(),
          fetchPets(),
      ] ,
      child: MyHousePage()
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try importing 'package:provider/provider.dart' as statemanagement; and use multi provider as statemanagement.MultiProvider(...), and use Provider as statemanagement.Provider(....) worked on my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart' as statemanagement;

import 'models/model_provider.dart';
import 'modules/screen_root.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return statemanagement.MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        statemanagement.Provider<ModelProvider>(
          create: ((_) => ModelProvider())),
        ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Multi Provider',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const ScreenRoot(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).